# CSS Style in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I don't know why my input element doesn't change color when hovering

```
<input
                    id='running'
                    className={filterButtonsSytles.button} 
                    style={{backgroundColor: this.state.running  ? 'grey':'white'}} 
                    type="button"
                    value="Bieganie"
                    onClick={(e)=>this.clickHandler(e)}
                />
```

css

```
.button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `{filterButtonsSytles.button}` ?

Comment: unless it is `.button` the above class won't apply

Comment: I import import filterButtonsSytles from './filterButtons.module.css';
 and in the filterButtons.css have this .button. Hover works when i delete 
"style={{backgroundColor: this.state.running  ? 'grey':'white'}} "

Comment: But i need  "style={{backgroundColor: this.state.running ? 'grey':'white'}} "  because this.state.running = true means that this button is active, and false that it isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give !important flag on hover because your style in in react element is inline style  and inline style does not let override by any external css

To make this right

```
.button:hover {
background-color: grey!important;
}
```

To make it more precise **!important** is not recommended . you should be using classes for this.